# How does Go handle stdout in Windows?

Tags: go

I was checking in Go's source code, and it seems the standard out (os.Stdout) points to:

```
os.Stdout = os.NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdout), "/dev/stdout")
```

But from my understanding, this should only work for Unix-based systems. And yet, it's defined as a general variable.

Comment: Why should it only work on unix systems? The syscall package will contain the correct constants for the current OS.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. There is no os.Stdout for windows.

Comment: I mean, it’s not called the exact same thing but you can see exactly what it’s doing in the source. `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` is defined, and the windows version of `NewFile` makes a windows file handle out of it.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft says Windows has a standard output device (stdout).

> [GetStdHandle function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle)
>
> STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE -   The standard output device.

The Windows specific Go `syscall.Stdout` variable is:

[go](https://github.com/golang/go)/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go:

```
var (
    Stdout = getStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
)
```

See [Go Build constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints) for OS specific files.

Answer (score 3):

The main important argument passed to `NewFile` is the first one, which is the *file handle*. The Windows syscall package correctly specifies a value for the standard output file (`syscall.Stdout`), so `os` just borrows it.

The point of the second argument is just to give the resulting `*os.File` value some kind of name that can be used, for example when calling `os.Stdout.Name()`, since the file handle doesn't carry a name by itself. You could argue that naming `os.Stdout` as `"/dev/stdout"` on Windows is confusing, but it's just a name that doesn't impact functionality.